# Why are the decision boundaries in binary classification with support vector machine overlapping on my plots?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I'm performing binary classification using scikit. Everything appears to be orderly in terms of prediction, but when I plot the decision boundaries, the decision boundaries are overlapping (see Plot). Now I realize now that MULTICLASS SVM will inevitably lead to decision boundaries overlapping, but why is this occurring with binary SVM classification? They should never overlap as far as I know since the space is being divided into two. So any idea why my plots look so disorderly and so many different colors when there should only be two colors? Is it how I am plotting? Thank you.

[Updated Picture with subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J1f5.png)

```
def createSVMandPlot(X,y,x_name,y_name):

    h = .02  # step size in the mesh

    # we create an instance of SVM and fit out data. We do not scale our
    # data since we want to plot the support vectors
    C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
    svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(X, y) #1 vs 1 
    rbf_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma='scale', C=C).fit(X, y) #1v1
    poly_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, gamma='scale',C=C).fit(X, y) #1v1
    lin_svc = svm.LinearSVC(C=C).fit(X, y) #1 vs rest

    print(str(x_name)+' vs. '+str(y_name))
    for i, clf in enumerate((svc, lin_svc, rbf_svc, poly_svc)):

        X_pred=clf.predict(X)
        X_pred1=np.asarray(X_pred).reshape(len(X_pred),1)
        A=confusion_matrix(X_pred1, y)
        print(A)
        c=0
        for r in range(len(X_pred)):
            if X_pred[r]==y[r]:
                c+=1

        print(str(c)+' out of 34 predicted correctly (true positives)')


    =============================================================================
    with warnings.catch_warnings():

        warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
        =============================================================================


        x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
        y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                             np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

        # title for the plots
        titles = ['SVC w/ linear kernel',
                  'LinearSVC (w/ linear kernel)',
                  'SVM w/ RBF kernel',
                  'SVM w/ poly(degree 3) kernel']

        plt.pause(7)
        for i, clf in enumerate((svc, lin_svc, rbf_svc, poly_svc)):
            # point in the mesh [x_min, x_max]x[y_min, y_max].
            plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
            plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.4)

            Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

            # Put the result into a color plot
            Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
            plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=.5)

            # Plot also the training points
            plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=13,c=y)
            plt.xlabel(x_name)
            plt.ylabel(y_name)
            plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
            plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
            plt.xticks(())
            plt.yticks(())
            plt.title(titles[i])

            plt.show()
```

Comment: you plotted the result of multiple support vector machines since you are looping.

Comment: It's in a subplot actually. I just took a picture of ONE of the 4 subplots. Or are you saying it's keeping the old figure from that subplot space (say 1st row, 1st column) during the next iteration and just plotting the new one on top in that space? Should I add plt.clf() somewhere I presume? Thanks

Comment: usually if you have subplots you get different axis objects on which you plot but you don't. Just try it without the subplots, so removing the two lines concerning the subplots should do.

Comment: UPDATE: Just fixed it by adding if(i%4)==0 then clearing the plot, but some regions are blank white for some reason (see new image called "Plot2" on my question). What could be causing this?

Comment: Actually that looks fine for me. Could you try to do it without `plt.contourf`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it without it. Could you suggest an alternative? So what does this white space represent? Just areas with no data points? I would have thought it would have colored each side of the support vector fully.

Comment: Yep, the white area represents just space without data points. Actually I think you did limit the bounds correctly but the plot shows the opposite. Could you print your boundaries and check if they are the same in your plot? If that does not work, I would try to get rid of the loops and just do that stuff for one svm

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "limit the bounds"? Which part of my code are you referring to? This is just a visual issue, correct?

Comment: The values you put in `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim`

Comment: I just commented those lines out, and the result was the one plot. All in all, the plots are fine now right? I don't care about the white space so I don't see any other glaring issues. What do you think is still a problem?

Comment: If you don't care about the white spots everything is fine. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Because you have four different Support vector machines :

svc , rbf_svc , poly_svc and lin_svc

And iteratively you are plotting all of them. That is the reason you are seeing the overlaps boundaries, because of 4 different boundaries shown in the same single plot

Comment: Please see the comments. This is just one of the plots in the subplot. I just added a more complete picture. Could you please explain why some parts are white?